# RazorEngine extension method fails with RuntimeBinderException after upgrade to Razor 2/ RE 3.2

Tags: razor, extension-methods, razor-2

I have a [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) project that fails following an upgrade to Razor 2.0 and RazorEngine 3.2.0

This worked fine in the previous Razor 1.0 based version of RazorEngine (3.0.8).

I have an instance (`myInstance`) of a class (`MyClass`) and and extension method:

```
namespace MyCompany.Extensions 
{
    public static class MyClassExtensions
    {
        public static string ExtensionMethod(this MyClass thing) 
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call this in a RazorEngine view (simplified example, there are loads of these methods, and all fail the same way):

```
@using MyCompany.Extensions
@using MyCompany
@{
    var myInstance = new MyClass(Model, ...);
}

Some text @myInstance.ExtensionMethod() some more text
```

This is in a text file that's compiled by RazorEngine:

```
string parsedResult = RE::Razor.Parse(fileContent, myModel, "testfile.txt");
```

The problem is that this line (which used to work) throws a `RuntimeBinderException`:

> 'MyCompany.MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'ExtensionMethod'

Note that if I change the text file to:

```
Some text @MyClassExtensions.ExtensionMethod(myInstance) some more text
```

It works fine, so I think it must find the extension method's namespace.

My first thought was that it must be considering the passed model as a `dynamic` (and hence anything derived from it as `dynamic` too), but it knows the expected type in the `RuntimeBinderException`. As the exception is run-time I think it must be failing to identify the extension method while the template is compiled, but why would that have changed?

I'm not sure what's changed between 3.0.8 and 3.2.0, or why this is broken. Is there something I need to add so that the extension method can be found while the template is compiled?

Comment: Is it working with the static method syntax? E.g `Some text @MyClassExtensions.ExtensionMethod(myInstance) some more text`

Comment: @nemesv yes `@MyClassExtensions.ExtensionMethod(myInstance)` works fine, but there are hundreds of extension methods in the Razor code (anything that returns display text is kept of the core library).

Comment: I've copied all your code in an empty console app with RazorEngine 3.2.0. And it works fine... can you try to repro your issue in a new project?

Comment: @nemesv I haven't tried a console app, but an otherwise empty MVC 4 app has the same symptoms. I need this working in an MVC application.

Comment: This seems like the same issue as https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/83, I haven't had a chance to look at the source of the problem, but I'll try and do so tonight for you.

Comment: @MatthewAbbott Cheers! That looks very similar - if I split out `Razor.Compile` and `Razor.Run` the error happens on the `Run` step. It compiles as if the extension method is an instance one, and then fails to find it, which suggests either VB-style late-binding or a `dynamic` model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug in RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/83): the `Razor.Compile` works on `TemplateBase<dynamic>` (so `Model` and everything derived from it is `dynamic` too) and that means that no extension methods undergo the 'compiler-magic' to convert them to the static calls. Then `Razor.Run` passes the `Model` as the correct type, but the extension method syntax is called as an instance method.

There will probably be a fix for this soon (the bug's only a few days old and this is a corner case), but in the meantime I have a workaround: *explicitly type the `Model` in the Razor template*

```
@using MyCompany.Extensions
@using MyCompany
@{
    ExpectedModelClass strongTypeModel = Model as ExpectedModelClass;
    MyClass myInstance = new MyClass(strongTypeModel , ...);
}

Some text @myInstance.ExtensionMethod() some more text
```

This now works, because even though `Model` is still `dynamic` at compile-time that doesn't spread to `myInstance` any more.

It's not ideal, and everywhere I used `Model` now has to be `strongTypeModel`, but that's a much simpler substitution.